# SQL Pivot and combine uneven number of records from row to column based on value

Tags: sql-server, pivot

Alrighty, I have a vicious stored proc that combines data from 10 or more tables.  I have simplified that procedure quite a bit for this example, but what I need at this point is to pivot data from a row to a column based on the value in LS#.  The tricky part is that I need to group/combine the data into one row based on values in the other 5 columns.  Here's the data my stored proc returns:

```
Calid  ID   GBID   Crs#     Sec#        CrsDesc    LS#
12     2    1449   239002   000001      Reading    02.RE.COM
12     2    1449   239002   000001      Reading    02.RE.DWR
12     2    1449   239002   000001      Reading    BE.K5.A.01
12     2    1449   239002   000001      Reading    BE.K5.B.01
12     2    1449   239002   000001      Reading    BE.K5.C.01
```

What I want is:

```
Calid  ID   GBID   Crs#     Sec#        CrsDesc    LS#         LSBE#
12     2    1449   239002   000001      Reading    02.RE.COM   BE.K5.A.01
12     2    1449   239002   000001      Reading    02.RE.DWR   BE.K5.B.01  
12     2    1449   239002   000001      Reading    NULL        BE.K5.C.01
```

At times, there will be more non BE records than non BE records, and vice versa, but I need all available rows to show up, with a blank or NULL in the appropriate field.  I'm sure this is easy for an sql genius out there, but it is totally eluding me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this is kinda cumbersome, but it works:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT  *,
            CASE WHEN [LS#] LIKE 'BE%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END IsBE,
            RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Calid, ID, [GBID],
                                                [Crs#], [Sec#], [CrsDesc],
                                                CASE WHEN [LS#] LIKE 'BE%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
                                   ORDER BY [LS#])
    FROM YourTable
)
SELECT  ISNULL(A.[Calid],B.[Calid]) [Calid], 
        ISNULL(A.[ID],B.[ID]) [ID], 
        ISNULL(A.[GBID],B.[GBID]) [GBID], 
        ISNULL(A.[Crs#],B.[Crs#]) [Crs#],
        ISNULL(A.[Sec#],B.[Sec#]) [Sec#], 
        ISNULL(A.[CrsDesc],B.[CrsDesc]) [CrsDesc], 
        A.[LS#] [LS#],
        B.[LS#] [LSBE#]
FROM (  SELECT * 
        FROM CTE
        WHERE IsBE = 0) A
FULL JOIN ( SELECT *
            FROM CTE
            WHERE IsBE = 1) B
    ON A.Calid = B.Calid
    AND A.ID = B.ID
    AND A.GBID = B.GBID 
    AND A.[Sec#] = B.[Sec#]
    AND A.CrsDesc = B.CrsDesc
    AND A.RN = B.RN;
```

[**Here is a sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b15a2/1) with a demo of it. And the results are:

```
╔═══════╦════╦══════╦════════╦══════╦═════════╦═══════════╦════════════╗
║ Calid ║ ID ║ GBID ║  Crs#  ║ Sec# ║ CrsDesc ║    LS#    ║   LSBE#    ║
╠═══════╬════╬══════╬════════╬══════╬═════════╬═══════════╬════════════╣
║    12 ║  2 ║ 1449 ║ 239002 ║    1 ║ Reading ║ 02.RE.COM ║ BE.K5.A.01 ║
║    12 ║  2 ║ 1449 ║ 239002 ║    1 ║ Reading ║ 02.RE.DWR ║ BE.K5.B.01 ║
║    12 ║  2 ║ 1449 ║ 239002 ║    1 ║ Reading ║ NULL      ║ BE.K5.C.01 ║
╚═══════╩════╩══════╩════════╩══════╩═════════╩═══════════╩════════════╝
```